# Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) doesn't matter any more?

Tags: excel, vba

For as long as I can remember, I've always used Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) if I want to copy only the visible values from a filtered column to a new location. I have it in my head that if I *didn't* specify .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), it would copy all the values in the column.

For example, Sheet1 has 30 values in column A, and I have applied an autofilter so that only 4 rows are visible. I would do this to copy only those 4 values to Sheet2:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

Now I have a scenario where I'd like to copy all 30 values regardless of whether or not a filter is in effect. I thought I could just do this:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
```

...but no, that still only copies the 4 visible rows!

Am I crazy, or did Microsoft render .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) obsolete at some point?

And any suggestions for how I could copy the entire column regardless of whether or not a filter is in effect, apart from iterating through all the rows in the column?

I'm using the Office 365 Excel, version 2208.

Comment: You are not crazy, but Microsoft didn't change anything either. `Range("A2:A31").Value` or other ways of enumerating the range will return all cells, filtered or not. `.Copy` will only take visible cells. This was always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy the entire column regardless of whether or not a filter is in place, you can assign the values of the range into an `array` and then assign the values of the `array` into the new range.

Do note that you need to specify the range to assign the values to

```
Dim var As Variant
    
var = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31").Value2
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A30").Value2 = var
```

Comment: In fairness you _can_ do that directly, without involving an array at all, i.e. `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A30").Value2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A31").Value2`

Comment: Oh true, it completely slipped my mind for some reason lol